# Laravel syntax error in trying to load simple view: unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'

Tags: arrays, laravel, variables, syntax

Just starting out with Laravel. I am simply trying to pass a variable into a data array and load the view, but come up with the following syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'
```

I've tried re-arranging the way I formatted the data array, to no avail. What am I missing?

**hello.blade.php file**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $someData ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

web.php (routes)

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/hello', function () {
    $variable = 'Hello from inside a v';
    return view('hello',data[
    'someData' => $variable,
    ]);
});
```

The error is coming up as being with this line:

```
'someData' => $variable,
```

I have tried it with and without the comma after $variable - but that didn't work either. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I know I could use different notation or blade, but at the moment, I just want to know why this doesn't work. There is another stackoverflow question with a similar title, but it wasn't able to address my specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `data` you have in there. It is a syntax error.

```
Route::get('/hello', function () {
    $variable = 'Hello from inside a v';
    return view('hello', [
        'someData' => $variable,
    ]);
});
```

Please also see Blade syntax in `.blade.php` files: https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#displaying-data

hello.blade.php should be more like:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>{{ $someData }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jonathan, thank you for posting. You've suggested I remove the 'data' from before the first square bracket. Is there a reason for why this works? The tutorial I followed used it, and I've seen it in other articles. Together with your answer - thank you - any explanation would be appreciated (and I'm sure helpful for others!)

Comment: This is the tutorial being followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdTp_d48XwE  - is it using the wrong version of something? Could you suggest what?

Comment: What you're seeing is a quirk of the text editor that the author is using. It is most likely looking up the original definition of the function for `view()`, and then suggesting to you what the parameters of that function should be, based on the parameter names in the original function definition. Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: I just noted that using data: (before the square bracket worked!). So  - a data array it is referencing?

Comment: return view('hello',data:[
 'someData' => $variable,
 ]);
 });

Comment: Yeah, if you look in the video again, you can see that `data:` is greyed out and appears automatically. That is not code that the author has written. It is some magic in the editor to help the programmer be more productive, by providing them with more information about the function they are using.

Comment: See what might be the function definition from the API here https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_view as you can see, the view function expects the follow arguments `view(string|array $view, array $data = [], int $status = 200, array $headers = [])`. The author's editor is retrieving the names of the parameters, in this case `view` and `data`